# how to capitalize every single char while typing in a text area using Acrobat javascript?

Tags: javascript, adobe, acrobat, onkeydown, capitalize

i want to capitalize every single char within an text area while typing and using Adobe Acrobat

But how can i do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Text Field "Properties" under the "Format" tab enter the following javascript into the Custom Keystroke script box:

```
event.change = event.change.toUpperCase();
```